# How to make chrome.webRequest wait for results of XMLHttpRequest();

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a Chrome Extension where I want to block the loading of a page based on an external lookup (e.g., check a spam rating or other service based on the URL the user typed into the entry bar).

From the Chrome Developer Docs, they provide the [following basic example for blocking](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
    {urls: ["*://www.evil.com/*"]},
    ["blocking"]);
```

The problem I am having is trying to figure out the right way of using callbacks, promises, or async/await so I can determine if I want to return true and block the web page from loading.

---

For example, this will work:

```
function returnTrue(){
  return {cancel: true};
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  returnTrue,
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"],
    types: ["main_frame"]
  },
  ["blocking"]);
```

but if I make `returnTrue()` async the listener no longer blocks, and the page loads. e.g.,

```
async function returnTrue(){
  return {cancel: true};
}
```

---

In my real function I tried using await on the results of a promise which wraps 
 `XMLHttpRequest()`. Prior to that, I tried making it synchronous when I call `XMLHttpRequest().open()` by setting the last parameter false. This cause execution to by synchronous, but its deprecated functionality and it cause some other weird problems that made ,send() fail with errors. I would therefore like to avoid forcing `.open()` synchronous.

I also tried putting the `async` keyword before `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest...` but that doesn't work either.

---

How can I ensure that I force the Chrome addon to wait until I called the remote service and made a decision before it executes. Since this is blocking the loading, it really should all be synchronous logic or at least await before making the blocking decision.

Comment: I don't think `webRequest.onBeforeRequest` can handle a promise being returned by the listener - at least, not in chrome - nothing in Chrome's (abysmal) documentation about this mentions promises

Comment: Chrome API is callback-based which is explicitly stated in all descriptions of methods in the documentation so async/await won't work since it's Promise-based. Hence the only available method is the synchronous XHR. You can disregard the deprecation warning. You can also add a timeout to make sure your background page isn't blocked for more than the specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchrony is not yet supported.

One compromise is to implement caching down the content you want to modify.